# how to upload an image using json api in rails 4 and postman

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, rails-api, postman

I am working on rails 4 application where I can upload images with description. I can upload images on web application but I want to test the json API. 
I want to upload image from HTTP POST on postman Rest client of chrome browser, But I cant seem to make it to work.

```
def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)
    @pin.save
    respond_with(@pin)
  end
 def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :user_id, :image, :tag_list)
    end
```

Here's my complete Pins controller, [here](https://gist.github.com/nileshlg2003/d681f39ea4c1b7f9078c)

I am using paperclip 4.2 gem for image upload and amazon s3 storage

Comment: If you have a look at the model, have you configured the model using has_attached_file ?